# Exhaust fan replacement e type housing unit

Tags: exhaust-fan

Okay. I spent couple of hours (or days :) ) on this now and I need to ask for help. We have one old model exhaust fan in the house that has never worked. I learnt after hours of looking up, that the model is discontinued and I can't just replace the motor. Wiring is also different. 3 pins instead of a plug.

I am still hoping to see if I can keep the existing housing assembly and replace the rest with a new unit but from my research I cant find a model that matches. I am going to email Broan as well but not sure if they will help out. I would love some help on how to find the replacement without moving the housing. The housing unit says it is "e housing type" vs what I saw at the store seem to be "d housing type". Pics attached (click to enlarge). Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why would anyone ask you that? I have spent hours looking for exact that. If anyone has tips on what I can try next that would be helpful. I don't know if you value my effort and time to post that comment but I definitely respect yours and what I have read in this forum today.

Comment: OK, remove the motor/fan, replace the brush contacts, motor coils do not go bad, need to find the right size brush contacts. If there is a capacitor, replace it

Comment: You have other identical fans?  Have you tried swapping the internals to see if it works in other locations?

Comment: Does the fan turn freely by hand?

Comment: I would suggest contacting Broan. It's likely they'll tell you to replace the whole thing (after all, that's how they make money), but they may have some old ones still in stock that they'd be willing to sell you directly. You may even get a good price on it!